# VirtualBox on ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: server, virtualbox, virtualization, amazon-ec2

Hey I am trying to find a solution for running a virtualbox on ec2 ubuntu instance. I have created a ec2 instance where I have installed virtualbox but for some reason I am getting some error called setting not detected.

Let me brief what I have done so far.
 First I have created a t2 micro instance with ubuntu as server.
 Then I installed a gui for server.
  And then Using vnc server I am accessing the ubuntu server from my ubunut desktop.
And then I have installed virtual box on that instance and it runs ok.
But when I am trying to add iso file it says:

invalid settings detected

I am getting this error on all the settings tab like storage and network.

So my question is very simple can we run virtualbox on ec2 instance?
If yes then on which type of instance and what are things which I need to run virtualbox.

Comment: You're almost certain to find that vbox can't run successfully on EC2 because an EC2 instance *is* a virtual machine, specifically, Xen.  As such, you lack the low-level CPU access that virtualbox requires.

Comment: My virtualbox is running and I am also able to install android os on m2 large instance. All I need an instance which provide few graphics. Do you know any instance. My android os hangs on android splash screen.